# web-scraping with selenium webdriver - using recursion

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape this website: [https://glaw.scourt.go.kr/wsjo/panre/sjo100.do?contId=3225630&q=*&nq=&w=panre&section=panre_tot&subw=&subsection=&subId=1&csq=&groups=6,7,5,9&category=&outmax=1&msort=&onlycount=&sp=&d1=20000101~20201231&d2=&d3=&d4=&d5=&pg=1&p1=&p2=&p3=&p4=&p5=&p6=&p7=01&p8=&p9=&p10=&p11=&p12=&sysCd=WSJO&tabGbnCd=&saNo=&joNo=&lawNm=&hanjaYn=N&userSrchHistNo=&poption=&srch=&range=&daewbyn=N&smpryn=N&idgJyul=01&newsimyn=Y&trtyNm=&tabId=&save=Y&bubNm=](https://glaw.scourt.go.kr/wsjo/panre/sjo100.do?contId=3225630&q=*&nq=&w=panre&section=panre_tot&subw=&subsection=&subId=1&csq=&groups=6,7,5,9&category=&outmax=1&msort=&onlycount=&sp=&d1=20000101%7E20201231&d2=&d3=&d4=&d5=&pg=1&p1=&p2=&p3=&p4=&p5=&p6=&p7=01&p8=&p9=&p10=&p11=&p12=&sysCd=WSJO&tabGbnCd=&saNo=&joNo=&lawNm=&hanjaYn=N&userSrchHistNo=&poption=&srch=&range=&daewbyn=N&smpryn=N&idgJyul=01&newsimyn=Y&trtyNm=&tabId=&save=Y&bubNm=)

It has two buttons at the very top left of the page `<이전글` (previous item) and `다음글` (next item). The url above shows the very first item, hence clicking on `<이전글`(previous item) simply refreshes the same page.

I am trying to scrape the content in the right box of each of the pages, until I reach the very last item (i.e. until clicking on  `다음글` (next item) would only refresh the same page).

From inspecting the page, if the item is the very last item, then the `a[href]` of the button `다음글` (next item) is simply `"#//`, while for all previous items their `a[href]`s of the button `다음글` (next item) are the url for the next item.

My code is as below (using recursion), but the urls that get printed out from the print statement tend to be duplicated as time goes by (they are printed twice or more).

If I don't include `time.sleep(4)`,  I get an error pretty much immediately after the same url gets printed for almost 10 times.

Am I missing something?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import sys
import re
from tqdm import tqdm
import time


sys.path.insert(0,'/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver')

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
chrome_options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.117 Safari/537.36")

wd = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)

start_url = "https://glaw.scourt.go.kr/wsjo/panre/sjo100.do?contId=3225630&q=*&nq=&w=panre&section=panre_tot&subw=&subsection=&subId=1&csq=&groups=6,7,5,9&category=&outmax=1&msort=&onlycount=&sp=&d1=20000101~20201231&d2=&d3=&d4=&d5=&pg=1&p1=&p2=&p3=&p4=&p5=&p6=&p7=01&p8=&p9=&p10=&p11=&p12=&sysCd=WSJO&tabGbnCd=&saNo=&joNo=&lawNm=&hanjaYn=N&userSrchHistNo=&poption=&srch=&range=&daewbyn=N&smpryn=N&idgJyul=01&newsimyn=Y&trtyNm=&tabId=&save=Y&bubNm="
content_l = []


def scrape(webdriver, url, l):
  time.sleep(4)
  wd.get(url)
  html = wd.page_source
  soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

  for i in soup.find("div", {"class:", "con_area_02"}).find_all(["h2","p"]):
    l.append(i.text)
  
  next_btn = wd.find_element_by_css_selector('a[title="다음글"]')

  if str(next_btn.get_attribute("href")) != "#//":
    next_btn = wd.find_element_by_css_selector('a[title="다음글"]')
    print(str(next_btn.get_attribute("href")))
    #next_btn.click()
    time.sleep(1)
    return scrape(webdriver, str(next_btn.get_attribute("href")), l)
  elif str(next_btn.get_attribute("href")) == "#//":
    return l 


scrape(wd, start_url, content_l)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its because you are not performing `click()` after you locate the `next_btn`. So it enters the `if loop` and same `url` is passed again.

Update: This is the code I tried.

```
driver.get("https://glaw.scourt.go.kr/wsjo/panre/sjo100.do?contId=3225630&q=*&nq=&w=panre&section=panre_tot&subw=&subsection=&subId=1&csq=&groups=6,7,5,9&category=&outmax=1&msort=&onlycount=&sp=&d1=20000101%7E20201231&d2=&d3=&d4=&d5=&pg=1&p1=&p2=&p3=&p4=&p5=&p6=&p7=01&p8=&p9=&p10=&p11=&p12=&sysCd=WSJO&tabGbnCd=&saNo=&joNo=&lawNm=&hanjaYn=N&userSrchHistNo=&poption=&srch=&range=&daewbyn=N&smpryn=N&idgJyul=01&newsimyn=Y&trtyNm=&tabId=&save=Y&bubNm=")
next = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@name='btnContNext']")
list1 = [next.get_attribute('href')]
next.click()
for i in range(5):
    time.sleep(2)
    nextoption = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@name='btnContNext']")
    if nextoption.get_attribute('href') in list1:
        print("Duplicate")
    else:
        list1.append(nextoption.get_attribute('href'))
        nextoption.click()
print(list1)
```

Comment: Thank you! But when I add next_btn.click() right before the if statement, I get the following error: StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: headless chrome=91.0.4472.101)

Comment: Yes, even I got the same error. Put the same line `next_btn = wd.find_element_by_css_selector('a[title="다음글"]')` inside the `if loop`. And it dint through that exception.

Comment: @pvalerie - I have updated the answer with code. It might be useful for you.

Comment: Thank you so, so much! I really appreciate it. Just a quick question, I guess I'll need to know how many elements I need to scrape in advance, right? So that I know what number to put in range(number)? Or is there a way I can figure out that number? (there is no such thing as 'last page' etc. in the page elements..)

Comment: Yes the next option doesn't have an end. So you need decide the required number of pages i.e. you need to choose range(number)